# Singular solution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been given the following differential equation:
$$y(y-2xy')^2=2y'$$

I was able to obtain a singular solution $4xy^2+1=0$. Now I need to verify that it is a solution of the differential equation.
I obtain this: $y^2=-\frac{1}{4x}$.

How do I proceed when there is a negative sign which would be inside of the square root?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $x$ was negative itself, this wouldn't be an issue, would it?

Comment: Noe that $y=0$ is also a solution

Comment: You can always verify an explicit solution by plugging it in to the differential equation and seeing if the two sides simplify to the same thing.  In this case, both $y = \sqrt{-1/(4x)}$ and $-\sqrt{-1/(4x)}$ qualify.  BTW, it's also easy to see that if $y$ is a solution, so is $-y$.

Answer (score 1):

First take your solution $y^2=-1/(4x)$ and differentiate implicitly, thus

$2yy'=1/(4x^2)$

$y'=1/(8x^2y).$

We then have

$y[y-1/(4xy)]^2=1/(4x^2y)$

$y^3-y/(2x)+1/(16x^2y)=1/(4x^2y).$

Now divide by $y$, which is valid because $y^2=-1/(4x)$ forces $y\not=0$:

$y^2-1/(2x)+1/(16x^2y^2)=1/(4x^2y^2).$

Then you have only even powers of $y$ so you can exchange $y^2$ for $-1/4x$ in the last equation above.  You then have an equation with $x$ alone.  If this can be reduced algebraically to an identity, your solution is verified.